Part name of this IC - "LLA#537"
I want to know the part numbers of the components marked as shown in the attached image.


Without knowing any more than what is in the post, like dimensions and surrounding circuitry;
It's likely to be an Analog Devices ADP3334ACPZ, High Accuracy, Low IQ, anyCAP®
Adjustable Low Dropout Regulator in 8-Lead Lead Frame Chip Scale Package.

source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3334.pdf

Thank you so much
